# Angular UI-Router link with parameter not working

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have the following code:

```
  $stateProvider.state('dm', {
    template: '<div ui-view></div>'
  }).state('dm.start', {
    url: '/',
    templateUrl: 'test.html'
  }).state('dm.view', {
    url: '/view',
    template: '<div ui-view></div>',
    controller: 'ViewCtrl',
    controllerAs: "$ctrl"
  }).state('dm.view.deposit', {
    url: '/deposit',
    templateUrl: 'components/view/view_deposit.html'
  }).state('dm.view.lot', {
    url: '/lot',
    templateUrl: 'components/view/view_lot.html'
  }).state('dm.add', {
    url: '/add',
    template: '<div ui-view></div>',
    controller: 'AddCtrl',
    controllerAs: "$ctrl"
  }).state('dm.add.deposit', {
    url: '/deposit',
    templateUrl: 'components/add/add_deposit.html'
  }).state('dm.add.lot', {
    url: '/lot',
    templateUrl: 'components/add/add_lot.html'
  }).state('dm.add.lot.main', {
    url: '/:id',
    templateUrl: 'components/add/add_lot_main.html',
    controller: 'AddLotMainCtrl',
    controllerAs: "$ctrl"
  });
```

When I try to navigate to add/lot/1234, though, it shows that in the URL box but I get the page components/add/add_lot.html. How do I go to components/add/add_lot_main.html?

Comment: Change last state's name to 'dm.add.lotmain' & url as '/lot/:id' that should probably solve the issue.

Comment: Try to invert the order of your states. put .state('dm.add.lot.main' before .state('dm.add.lot', and see if it works

Answer (score 0):

All the settings seem to be ok. Assure, that template `'components/add/add_lot.html'` really contains a target for its child

```
<div ui-view=""></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing to url for lot/:id

**JS**

```
.state('dm.add.lot.main', {
url: '/lot/:id',
templateUrl: 'components/add/add_lot_main.html',
controller: 'AddLotMainCtrl',
controllerAs: "$ctrl"
```

});

This will resolve it.